# Cannot use fine grained password policy in PowerShell or ADAC

Tags: windows, powershell, server, passwords

we are trying to create a fine grained password policy in ADAC and the "NEW" button is greyed out where we usually click to create a new policy. We are not sure why that happened as it has worked before. We have our DC's all set to the highest function level in both domain and forest to 2016. We have all DC's on server 2016.

**We tried to do it in PowerShell with the command:**

```
New-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy -name "PASSTEST" -Precedence 1 -MinPasswordLength 15
```

**This is the output we are getting from PowerShell:**
We are stuck as we are not sure what happened or how to resolve this. We would like to make fine grain password policy work again.

```
New-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy : The object cannot be added because the parent is not on the list of possible
superiors
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy -name "PASSTEST" -Precedence 1 -MinPa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=PASSTEST,CN=...k12,DC=ca,DC=us:String) [New-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolic
   y], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8345,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADFineGraine
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't already have a fine grained password policy with a precedence of 1? You can check with `Get-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy -Filter *`. The recommendation is to set them in increments of 10 so that there's room for more later.

Comment: We tried that command and nothing comes up.                                                                PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy -Filter *
PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32>